# ESP8266 sends data to the website but doesn't return status

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, iot

I have problem with my esp8266 it connects to my site and sends 89 bytes of data but does return a confirmation status all i get is SEND OK but i don't get any confirmation from my server

This is my code below

```
 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include<time.h>

SoftwareSerial ESP8266(3, 2); // RX, TX
//DEFINE ALL GLOBAL VAARIABLES HERE
unsigned int timeout_start_val;
char scratch_data_from_ESP[20];//first byte is the length of bytes
char payload[150];
byte payload_size=0, counter=0;
char ip_address[16];
char youtube_subs[10];
char youtube_views[13];
char current_temp[5];
char hi_temp[5];
char lo_temp[5];

//MODES
const char CWMODE = '3';//CWMODE 1=STATION, 2=APMODE, 3=BOTH
const char CIPMUX = '1';//CIPMUX 0=Single Connection, 1=Multiple Connections
//PASS word

const char SSID_ESP[]="Xamel";//"AOTEA TZ";//from constant 

const char SSID_KEY[]="cewu5103";//"wyrnC592";

//DEFINE KEYWORDS HERE
const char keyword_OK[]="OK";
const char keyword_FAIL[]="FAIL";
const char keyword_Ready[] = "Ready";
const char keyword_no_change[] = "no change";
const char keyword_blank[] = "#&";
const char keyword_ip[] = "192.";
const char keyword_rn[] = "\r\n";
const char keyword_quote[] = "\"";
const char keyword_carrot[] = ">";
const char keyword_sendok[] = "SEND OK";
const char keyword_linkdisc[] = "Unlink";
const char keyword_CHECKCWMODE[] = "+CWMODE:3";
const char keyword_URL_CONNECTION_ERROR[]="Link typ ERROR";
const char TEST_URL[]="";

const char GET_URL[]="GET /ESP8266_BackEnd/SaveDetail.php?Name=";
int str1=strlen(GET_URL);
const char Name[]="Alex ";
int str2=strlen(Name);


const char TRAILING_URL[]="HTTP/1.1 \\r\\nHost: www.pick2get.com\\r\\n\\r\\n";
int str3=strlen(TRAILING_URL);
int strTotal=str1+str2+str3;

const char AT_CIPSTART[]="AT+CIPSTART=4,\"TCP\",\"pick2get.com\",80 \r\n";
const char AT_CIPSEND[]="AT+CIPSEND=4,";
//function prototype
boolean read_until_ESP(const char keyword1[], int key_size, int timeout_val, byte mode);
void serial_dump_ESP();
boolean setup_ESP(const char SSID_ESP[],const char SSID_KEY);
String url="&School=4D616B6F6E676F";
void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  //.print("Total string length");Serial.println(strTotal);

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  ESP8266.begin(9600);
  //

  //Serial.println(read_until_ESP(keyword_URL_CONNECTION_ERROR,sizeof(keyword_URL_CONNECTION_ERROR),5000,0));
  setup_ESP(SSID_ESP,SSID_KEY);

  ESP8266.print(AT_CIPSTART);
  ESP8266.print("");
  delay(1000);

  ESP8266.print(AT_CIPSEND);
  ESP8266.print(strTotal);
  ESP8266.print("\r\n");
  delay(1000);
  ESP8266.print("");
  ESP8266.print(GET_URL);
  ESP8266.print(Name);
  ESP8266.print(TRAILING_URL);
  delay(1000);
  ESP8266.print("");
  //ESP8266.println("&Grade=466F726D204F6E65");        
  //ESP8266.println("&DeviceIP=3139322E3136382E302E31");         
  //ESP8266.println(TRAILING_URL);



}

void loop() { // run over and over
  byte buffer[300];
  if (ESP8266.available()) {
   Serial.write(ESP8266.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    ESP8266.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

This is the output generated on the serial monitor

```
ESP CHECK OK
ESP RESET OK
ESP RESET OK
timeout
ESP CWMODE SET FAILED
CWMODE ALREADY SET
SETTING SSID_ESP: Xamel
SETTING SSID_KEY: cewu5103
ESP SSID SET OK DEVICE CONNECTED
CHECKING FOR AN IP ADDRESS
IP ADDRESS = 192.168.4.1
ESP CIPMUX SET
AT+CIPSTART=4,"TCP","pick2get.com",80 


OK
Linked
AT+CIPSEND=4,89

> GET /ESP8266_BackEnd/SaveDetail.php?Name=Alex HTTP/1.1 \r\nHost: www.pick2get.com\r\n\r\n
SEND OK

OK
Unlink
```

Can any one please help here.

When adding ESP8266.print("+IPD\r\n"); this is the output i get

```
    ESP CHECK OK
ESP RESET OK
ESP RESET OK
timeout
ESP CWMODE SET FAILED
CWMODE ALREADY SET
SETTING SSID_ESP: Xamel
SETTING SSID_KEY: cewu5103
ESP SSID SET OK DEVICE CONNECTED
CHECKING FOR AN IP ADDRESS
IP ADDRESS = 192.168.4.1
ESP CIPMUX SET
AT+CIPSTART=4,"TCP","pick2get.com",80 

AT+CIPSEND=4,89

busy p...

OK
Linked
GET /ESP8266_BackEnd/SaveDetail.php?Name=Alex HTTP/1.1 \r\nHost: www.pick2get.com\r\n\r\n

wrong syntax

ERROR
AT+IPD


ERROR
```

I have managed to fix the lack of server response by removing the \r\n \nd replacing them with regular \r\n\r\n

```
enter code here
const char TRAILING_URL[]="HTTP/1.1 \r\nHost: www.pick2get.com \r\n\r\n";
int str3=strlen(TRAILING_URL);
int strTotal=str1+str2+str3;

const char AT_CIPSTART[]="AT+CIPSTART=4,\"TCP\",\"pick2get.com\",80 \r\n";
const char AT_CIPSEND[]="AT+CIPSEND=4,";
```

At this lines and was able to get a server response

+IPD,4,392:HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 15 May 2018 12:07:08 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

400 Bad Request
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

finally i have debugged and fixed all the errors and the code works just fine 
This and server returns a status 200

turns out it was just me pointing GET request in the wrong folder path with this line code at in the GET_URL variable

const char GET_URL[]="GET pick2get.com/ESP8266_BackEnd/SaveDetail.php?Name=";

I replaced with this

const char GET_URL[]="GET /ESP8266_BackEnd/SaveDetail.php?Name=";

And got the desired result

+IPD,4,166:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 15 May 2018 12:2249 GMT
Server: Apache
Upgrade: h2
Connection: Upgrade
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

2

OK

+IPD,4,191:16
Connected successfully
5c
 DATA TRANSMITTED SUCSSEFULLYSTUDENT NAME RECIVED: Alex
STUDENT SCHOOL NAME RECIVED: 
3b
STUDENT GRADE RECIVED: 
DEVICE IP ADDREESS RECIVED:

OK

+IPD,4,42:1f
New record created successfully
0
Thanks a lot guys below is the complete working code

```
    /*
  Software serial multple serial test

 Receives from the hardware serial, sends to software serial.
 Receives from software serial, sends to hardware serial.

 The circuit:
 * RX is digital pin 10 (connect to TX of other device)
 * TX is digital pin 11 (connect to RX of other device)

 Note:
 Not all pins on the Mega and Mega 2560 support change interrupts,
 so only the following can be used for RX:
 10, 11, 12, 13, 50, 51, 52, 53, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69

 Not all pins on the Leonardo and Micro support change interrupts,
 so only the following can be used for RX:
 8, 9, 10, 11, 14 (MISO), 15 (SCK), 16 (MOSI).

 created back in the mists of time
 modified 25 May 2012
 by Nolawi solomon



 */
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include<time.h>

SoftwareSerial ESP8266(3, 2); // RX, TX
//DEFINE ALL GLOBAL VAARIABLES HERE
unsigned int timeout_start_val;
char scratch_data_from_ESP[20];//first byte is the length of bytes
char payload[150];
byte payload_size=0, counter=0;
char ip_address[16];


//MODES
const char CWMODE = '3';//CWMODE 1=STATION, 2=APMODE, 3=BOTH
const char CIPMUX = '1';//CIPMUX 0=Single Connection, 1=Multiple Connections
//PASS word

const char SSID_ESP[]="Xamel";//"AOTEA TZ";//from constant 

const char SSID_KEY[]="cewu5103";//"wyrnC592";

//DEFINE KEYWORDS HERE
const char keyword_OK[]="OK";
const char keyword_FAIL[]="FAIL";
const char keyword_Ready[] = "Ready";
const char keyword_no_change[] = "no change";
const char keyword_blank[] = "#&";
const char keyword_ip[] = "192.";
const char keyword_rn[] = "\r\n";
const char keyword_quote[] = "\"";
const char keyword_carrot[] = ">";
const char keyword_sendok[] = "SEND OK";
const char keyword_linkdisc[] = "Unlink";
const char keyword_CHECKCWMODE[] = "+CWMODE:3";
const char keyword_URL_CONNECTION_ERROR[]="Link typ ERROR";
//const char TEST_URL[]="";

const char GET_URL[]="GET /ESP8266_BackEnd/SaveDetail.php?Name=";
int str1=strlen(GET_URL);
const char Name[]="Alex ";
int str2=strlen(Name);


const char TRAILING_URL[]="HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.pick2get.com \r\n\r\n";
int str3=strlen(TRAILING_URL);
int strTotal=str1+str2+str3;

const char AT_CIPSTART[]="AT+CIPSTART=4,\"TCP\",\"pick2get.com\",80 \r\n";
const char AT_CIPSEND[]="AT+CIPSEND=4,";
//function prototype
boolean read_until_ESP(const char keyword1[], int key_size, int timeout_val, byte mode);
void serial_dump_ESP();
boolean setup_ESP(const char SSID_ESP[],const char SSID_KEY);
//String url="&School=4D616B6F6E676F";
void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  //.print("Total string length");Serial.println(strTotal);

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  ESP8266.begin(9600);
  //

  //Serial.println(read_until_ESP(keyword_URL_CONNECTION_ERROR,sizeof(keyword_URL_CONNECTION_ERROR),5000,0));
  setup_ESP(SSID_ESP,SSID_KEY);

  ESP8266.print(AT_CIPSTART);
  ESP8266.print("");
  delay(1000);

  ESP8266.print(AT_CIPSEND);
  ESP8266.print(strTotal);
  ESP8266.print("\r\n");
  delay(1000);
  ESP8266.print("");
  ESP8266.print(GET_URL);
  ESP8266.print(Name);
  ESP8266.print(TRAILING_URL);
  //delay(3000);
  //ESP8266.print("");
  //delay(2000);
  //ESP8266.print("\r\n");
  //delay(2000);
  //ESP8266.print("");
  //ESP8266.print("AT+IPD\r\n");
  //ESP8266.println("&Grade=466F726D204F6E65");        
  //ESP8266.println("&DeviceIP=3139322E3136382E302E31");         
  //ESP8266.println(TRAILING_URL);



}

void loop() { // run over and over
  byte buffer[300];
  if (ESP8266.available()) {
   Serial.write(ESP8266.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    ESP8266.write(Serial.read());
  }
}


boolean read_until_ESP(const char keyword1[], int key_size, int timeout_val, byte mode){
  timeout_start_val=millis();//for the timeout
  char data_in[20];//this is the buffer - if keyword is longer than 20, then increase this
  int scratch_length=1;//the length of the scratch data array
  key_size--;//since we're going to get an extra charachter from the sizeof()

 //FILL UP THE BUFFER
 for(byte i=0; i<key_size; i++){//we only need a buffer as long as the keyword

            //timing control
            while(!ESP8266.available()){//wait until a new byte is sent down from the ESP - good way to keep in lock-step with the serial port
              if((millis()-timeout_start_val)>timeout_val){//if nothing happens within the timeout period, get out of here
                Serial.println("timeout");
                return 0;//this will end the function
              }//timeout
            }// while !avail

    data_in[i]=ESP8266.read();// save the byte to the buffer 'data_in[]

    if(mode==1){//this will save all of the data to the scratch_data_from
      scratch_data_from_ESP[scratch_length]=data_in[i];//starts at 1
      scratch_data_from_ESP[0]=scratch_length;// [0] is used to hold the length of the array
      scratch_length++;//increment the length
    }//mode 1

  }//for i

//THE BUFFER IS FULL, SO START ROLLING NEW DATA IN AND OLD DATA OUT
  while(1){//stay in here until the keyword found or a timeout occurs

     //run through the entire buffer and look for the keyword
     //this check is here, just in case the first thing out of the ESP was the keyword, meaning the buffer was actually filled with the keyword
     for(byte i=0; i<key_size; i++){
       if(keyword1[i]!=data_in[i])//if it doesn't match, break out of the search now
       break;//get outta here
       if(i==(key_size-1)){//we got all the way through the keyword without breaking, must be a match!
       return 1; //return a 1 and get outta here!
       }//if
     }//for byte i


    //start rolling the buffer
    for(byte i=0; i<(key_size-1); i++){// keysize-1 because everthing is shifted over - see next line
      data_in[i]=data_in[i+1];// so the data at 0 becomes the data at 1, and so on.... the last value is where we'll put the new data
    }//for


           //timing control
            while(!ESP8266.available()){// same thing as done in the buffer
              if((millis()-timeout_start_val)>timeout_val){
                Serial.println("timeout");
                return 0;
              }//timeout
            }// while !avail



    data_in[key_size-1]=ESP8266.read();//save the new data in the last position in the buffer

      if(mode==1){//continue to save everything if thsi is set
      scratch_data_from_ESP[scratch_length]=data_in[key_size-1];
      scratch_data_from_ESP[0]=scratch_length;
      scratch_length++;
    }//mode 1

    /*  JUST FOR DEBUGGING
    if(ESP8266.overflow())
    Serial.println("*OVER");
    */

  }//while 1




}//read until ESP


boolean setup_ESP(const char SSID_ESP[],const char SSID_KEY[]){//returns a '1' if successful

  ESP8266.print("AT\r\n");// Send just 'AT' to make sure the ESP is responding
  //this read_until_... function is used to find a keyword in the ESP response - more on this later and in the function itself
  if(read_until_ESP(keyword_OK,sizeof(keyword_OK),5000,0))//go look for keyword "OK" with a 5sec timeout
    Serial.println("ESP CHECK OK");
  else
    Serial.println("ESP CHECK FAILED");
  serial_dump_ESP();//this just reads everything in the buffer and what's still coming from the ESP

   ESP8266.print("AT+RST\r\n");// Give it a reset - who knows what condition it was in, better to start fresh
  if(read_until_ESP(keyword_Ready,sizeof(keyword_Ready),5000,0))//go look for keyword "Ready" - takes a few seconds longer to complete
    Serial.println("ESP RESET OK");//depneding on the FW version on the ESP, sometimes the Ready is with a lowercase r - ready
  else
    Serial.println("ESP RESET FAILED"); 
  serial_dump_ESP();
  ESP8266.print("AT+RST\r\n");// Give it a reset - who knows what condition it was in, better to start fresh
  if(read_until_ESP(keyword_Ready,sizeof(keyword_Ready),5000,0))//go look for keyword "Ready" - takes a few seconds longer to complete
    Serial.println("ESP RESET OK");//depneding on the FW version on the ESP, sometimes the Ready is with a lowercase r - ready
  else
    Serial.println("ESP RESET FAILED"); 
  serial_dump_ESP();

   ESP8266.print("AT+CWMODE=");// set the CWMODE
   ESP8266.print(CWMODE);//just send what is set in the constant
   ESP8266.print("\r\n");
  if(read_until_ESP(keyword_OK,sizeof(keyword_OK),1000,0))//go look for keyword "OK"
    Serial.println("ESP CWMODE SET");
  else

    Serial.println("ESP CWMODE SET FAILED");//probably going to fail, since a 'no change' is returned if already set - would be nice to check for two words
    ESP8266.println("AT+CWMODE?");
    if(read_until_ESP(keyword_CHECKCWMODE,sizeof(keyword_CHECKCWMODE),1000,0))
    {
      Serial.println("CWMODE ALREADY SET");
      serial_dump_ESP();
    }
    serial_dump_ESP();  

   //Here's where the SSID and PW are set
   Serial.print("SETTING SSID_ESP: ");
   Serial.println(SSID_ESP);
   Serial.print("SETTING SSID_KEY: ");
   Serial.println(SSID_KEY);
   //DEbug poin


   ESP8266.print("AT+CWJAP=");//
   ESP8266.print("\""); 
   ESP8266.print(SSID_ESP);//
   ESP8266.print("\",\"");
   ESP8266.print(SSID_KEY);//
   ESP8266.print("\"\r\n");
  if(read_until_ESP(keyword_OK,sizeof(keyword_OK),5000,0)==1)//go look for keyword "OK"
    Serial.println("ESP SSID SET OK DEVICE CONNECTED");
  else if(read_until_ESP(keyword_FAIL,sizeof(keyword_FAIL),5000,0)==1)
    Serial.println("ESP SSID SET FAILED");   
  serial_dump_ESP();

  //This checks for and stores the IP address
  Serial.println("CHECKING FOR AN IP ADDRESS");
  ESP8266.print("AT+CIFSR\r\n");//command to retrieve IP address from ESP
  if(read_until_ESP(keyword_rn,sizeof(keyword_rn),10000,0)){//look for first \r\n after AT+CIFSR echo - note mode is '0', the ip address is right after this
  if(read_until_ESP(keyword_rn,sizeof(keyword_rn),1000,1)){//look for second \r\n, and store everything it receives, mode='1'
    //store the ip adress in its variable, ip_address[]
    for(int i=1; i<=(scratch_data_from_ESP[0]-sizeof(keyword_rn)+1); i++)//that i<=... is going to take some explaining, see next lines
       ip_address[i] = scratch_data_from_ESP[i];//fill up ip_address with the scratch data received
//i=1 because i=0 is the length of the data found between the two keywords, BUT this includes the length of the second keyword, so i<= to the length minus
//size of teh keyword, but remember, sizeof() will return one extra, which is going to be subtracted, so I just added it back in +1
    ip_address[0] = (scratch_data_from_ESP[0]-sizeof(keyword_rn)+1);//store the length of ip_address in [0], same thing as before
    Serial.print("IP ADDRESS = ");//print it off to verify
    for(int i=1; i<=ip_address[0]; i++)//send out the ip address
    Serial.print(ip_address[i]);
    Serial.println("");
  }}//if first \r\n
  else
  Serial.print("IP ADDRESS FAIL");
  serial_dump_ESP();

   ESP8266.print("AT+CIPMUX=");// set the CIPMUX
   ESP8266.print(CIPMUX);//from constant
   ESP8266.print("\r\n");
  if(read_until_ESP(keyword_OK,sizeof(keyword_OK),5000,0))//go look for keyword "OK" or "no change
    Serial.println("ESP CIPMUX SET");
  else
    Serial.println("ESP CIPMUX SET FAILED"); 
  serial_dump_ESP();


 //that's it!  Could be done by nesting everything together, so if one thing fails, it returns '0', and if it gets all the way through it returns '1'...oh well



}//setup ESP

//pretty simple function - read everything out of the serial buffer and whats coming and get rid of it
void serial_dump_ESP(){
  char temp;
  while(ESP8266.available()){
    temp =ESP8266.read();
    delay(1);//could play around with this value if buffer overflows are occuring
  }//while


}//serial dump
```

Comment: What happens when you write `+IPD\r\n` as the next AT command? (https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_AT/wiki/IPD)

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Can you elaborate more i am pretty much a beginner with the esp8266

Comment: I think you have to send this additional AT command to receive the data. Add `ESP8266.print("+IPD\r\n");` as the last statement in your `setup` function. Refer to https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf

Comment: I have added that AT command and it seems there is a syntax error

Comment: Edit your question with the updated code and the error then.

Comment: Can you try the command `"+IPD,500\r\n"`. This should request 500 bytes from the conenction. Try to play around with the number.

Comment: `\\r\\n`; are you sure you need to double escape those newlines?

Comment: @Gerben thanks alot apparently by replacing \\r\\n with the regular \r\n worked i am getting a response back apparently it status 400 but its progress still :)

Comment: @Gerben have ever had a situation where esp8266 would just hang after sending get request

Comment: I haven’t really done anything with an ESP. Try figuring out where the program halts. Most of the times it’s just a software problem. If the program sporadically stops working, you could look into enabling the WatchDog.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have "Connection: keep-alive" in your http header, default is "Connection: close" and that's why you never get anything in return from the server.

I have described it all together with a code sample in https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/54558/48149

The code sample uses the library WifiEsp to connect to ESP8266.

Comment: Yeah thanks i fixed that along time ago but still much respect for your contribution